# Call contract method from React

Tags: reactjs, nearprotocol

I'm new to `React` and `NEAR` and trying to understand how my frontend React app can call methods on the contract.

In the `near cli` i can call `near view $NFT_CONTRACT_ID nft_total_supply` which returns the amount of NFTs on the contract.

How do i call the same method from React.

I'm trying

```
  export async function CheckSupply() {
    const near = await connect(getConfig);
    const account = await near.account("mytestnetaccount.testnet");
    const supply = window.contract.nft_total_supply();
    console.log("please print this out")
  }
```

In my App.js i have a very basic page for now just to test the `console.log()` is being written out

```
const App = () =>{
  window.Buffer = window.Buffer || require("buffer").Buffer;
    const [userHasNFT, setuserHasNFT] = useState(false);  
   
    return (
        <>
        <div className="app">
            <WalletLogin />
            
            <div className="container">
            
                <img
                    alt=""
                    src={Logo}
                    width="360"
                    height="150"
                    className="d-inline-block align-top"
                />

            </div>
</>
};
```

But when I launch the app nothing is being written to the console.

I'm not sure why, but thinking it's because the function `CheckSupply` is not being called, but I want this to run when the app is rendered.

The `function CheckSupply()` is within my `utils.js` and being imported using `import { CheckSupply } from "./utils";`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call a function on mount in react functional component you can call that function in use effect with empty dependency array

checkout the code below and the link to learn more about effects in react

```
import { CheckSupply } from "./utils";
import {useEffect} from 'react';
    
const App = () =>{

window.Buffer = window.Buffer || require("buffer").Buffer;

const [userHasNFT, setuserHasNFT] = useState(false);  

useEffect(()=>{
    CheckSupply();
},[])

return (
    <>
    <div className="app">
        <WalletLogin />
        
        <div className="container">
        
            <img
                alt=""
                src={Logo}
                width="360"
                height="150"
                className="d-inline-block align-top"
            />

        </div>
    </>
};
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: Thanks Kartik. I did eventually discover that and seems to execute, but how do i capture the value of `supply` when executing within the `useEffect` hook?

Comment: Just return that amount and store it in a state

Comment: like this
`const [Total, setTotal] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        const load = async () => {
          const supply = await CheckSupply();
          setTotal(Total + supply)
        };
        load();
      }, [])`

Comment: Yes, if it doesn't work, can you share a code sandbox link